# Is it possible to pass two variables as part of a multiple typealias as a parameter?

Tags: swift

It's easier to explain with code than with text

```
class A {
    typealias Factory = PotatoFactoryProtocol & CarrotFactoryProtocol

    let factory: Factory

    init(factory: Factory) {
        self.factory = factory
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass both a `PotatoFactory()` and a `CarrotFactory()` into `A` due to `typealias Factory` accepting both? If not, how would be the best way pass multiple parameters of the same type, `Factory`, per example, in order to make it as clean as possible?

Comment: This doesn't make enough sense without knowing what `self.factory` is supposed to be.

Comment: Sorry @Jessy, I thought it was implicit, just edited the question :)

Comment: Now the code makes sense, but your question still doesn't. How do you plan to combine two values to make a single value? And you say "accepting both", but it doesn't. It accepts a value that conforms to both protocols, not a subset of that. You should add a couple of use cases.

Comment: I'd like to know if it's possible to send BOTH a PotatoFactory and a CarrotFactory as a parameter for the creation of this class instead of `init(potatoFactory: PotatoFactoryProtocol, carrotFactory: CarrotFactoryProtocol)` yet instead being able to send both (or more) under that single typealias.

Comment: Maybe figure out how you'd refer to what you're storing. Because `self.factory = factory` isn't going to work if `factory` isn't always the same type or something for which you can use generics.  It might even be a rubber duck situation after that.

Comment: If you want to replace `init(potatoFactory: PotatoFactoryProtocol, carrotFactory: CarrotFactoryProtocol)` with `init(factories: Factories)` that includes both, you'll need to create a new struct that contains both. This isn't what typealiases do. To make this question clear, you need to show what you think the calling code should look like.